# pg_stat_statements vs slow query

Tags: postgresql-13

Now I want to query the PostgreSQL 13 slow query that take more than 1s. Some told that should open the PostgreSQL slow query log, some recommand to use `pg_stat_statements`, which one should I choose? what is the performance effect with each one?